# Can we get result of a SSAS cube data into a rdbms table using java?

Tags: java, ssas, mdx

I am trying to get result of a SSAS cube data (not getting in a tabular format) and i am inserting into sql server, Want to know if there is any way to get SSAS cube data in a tabular format  using java?

Answer (score 0):

Do really need java? Try [olap4j](http://www.olap4j.org/).

Comment: i am trying with olap4j , i get the result as measures on columns and dimensions on rows. Is there resultset kind of in olap4j @Danylo Korostil

Comment: What do you mean resultset? I'm using python, not olap4j, and it is okay.

Comment: I want to read ssas cube using java.Do you get the result of a cube in tabular format(like a rdbms table)  @Danylo Korostil

Comment: You can use: https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/drjohn/archive/2008/09/27/mdx-and-sql-combining-relational-and-multi-dimensional-data-into-one-query-result-set.aspx

Comment: I don't see any restriction why you can't do it in java. I'm not java person, so won't help you with the code.